# how to merged this data only with 2 index?

Tags: python, pandas, artificial-intelligence

In:
`df.head_ache.value_counts()`

Out:

0        260079

0        16354

1         2065

1          349

how i merged this data only with 2 index?

Comment: Do you need `s = df.head_ache.value_counts()` and then `s.groupby(level=0).sum()` ?